# jQuery Compass - arrow to rotate on cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to create a 'compass style' circle in HTML and jQuery, in which the arrow rotates to a new section of the circle, depending on where the users cursor is.

I have the very basics setup, however I have a small bug caused by the rotate and CSS transition. Things look to be working fine until you attempt to move between the last section and the first section, because the rotate is jumping from a higher digit, all the way down to -45.

I think I need to instead just add or minus degrees based on the users cursor direction (i.e. 90 * (oldSection - newSection) - roughly speaking).
However I'm having trouble thinking through the logic. Could anyone shed any light on the easiest and smoothest way of achieving the desired affect?

My code can either be seen at http://jsbin.com/qaxikafixa/ - or below...

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="compass_container">
  <a id="square-1" class="square" href=""></a>
  <a id="square-2" class="square" href=""></a>
  <a id="square-3" class="square" href=""></a>
  <a id="square-4" class="square" href=""></a>
  <span class="arrow"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.compass_container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.compass_container .square {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.compass_container .square:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.compass_container .square:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}

.compass_container .square:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: orange;
}

.arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
  border-bottom: 60px solid white;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(320deg);
-webkit-transition: transform .25s ease;
     -moz-transition: transform .25s ease;
      -ms-transition: transform .25s ease;
       -o-transition: transform .25s ease;
          transition: transform .25s ease;
  }
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $(window).on('mousemove', function(event) {

    var mouseX = event.pageX;
    var mouseY = event.pageY;

    var arrow = $('.arrow');

    if (mouseX > $('#square-2').offset().left) {

      if (mouseY > $('#square-4').offset().top) {

        $(arrow).css({
          transform: 'rotate(135deg)'
        });

      } else {

        $(arrow).css({
          transform: 'rotate(45deg)'
        });

      }

    } else {

      if (mouseY > $('#square-3').offset().top) {

        $(arrow).css({
          transform: 'rotate(-135deg)'
        });

      } else {

        $(arrow).css({
          transform: 'rotate(-45deg)'
        });

      }

    }

  });

});
```

Comment: see my answer and let me know it is right or not ? or you want any help let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some modification in javascript.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/dvpss800/

```
var img = $('.arrow');
if(img.length > 0){
    var offset = img.offset();
    function mouse(evt){
        var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width()/2);
        var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height()/2);
        var mouse_x = evt.pageX; var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90; 
        img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    }
    $(document).mousemove(mouse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a way to get your rotation correctly using trigonometry. I'm not the world's best in trig, so I had to correct for Radians, but it does make your code much more readable and it actually works to more detail.

I hope this helps. I can;t really start explaining trigonometry here, but it comes down to this: the angle you are looking for is, for example A, and the values you know are x and y (x is the mouse position minus the center x). Thanks to the magic of `SOH CAH TOA` we know that the sinus of A is `y / (sqrt(x^2 + y^2))`, and that the cosinus is `x / (sqrt(x^2 + y^2))`. The one we really want, because it's simpler, is the tangent, which is `y / x`. If we inverse this tangent (atan), we get the angle. Now the only issue is that we get it in radians, so we convert it back to degrees and correct for mouse position to simulate full 180 degrees. Then we move the position to the right quadrant.

Hope this helps. If anyone with better trigonometry skills has improvements to this, please tell, since I'd like to know if it's possible to do it without the corrections for quadrant and radians in the end, but otherwise this works just fine and means you don't have to manually check for every possible location.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  
  $(window).on('mousemove', function(event) {
    
    
    var c = $("#compass");
    /*  . Mouse
     *  |\
     *  | \
     * y|  \
     *  |   \
     *  |____\. center of compass
     *     x
     */
    var x = c.offset().left + c.innerWidth() / 2 - event.pageX;
    var y = c.offset().top + c.innerHeight() / 2 - event.pageY;
    
    // Use the atan function to get the angle back 
    var angle = Math.atan(y / x) * 180 / Math.PI;
    
    // Correct for radians by adding one radian when we are further to the right
    // Also, correct for the angle's wrong quadrant
    angle = event.pageX > c.offset().left + c.innerWidth() / 2 ? angle + 90 : angle - 90;
    
    var arrow = $('.arrow').css({transform: 'rotate(' + (angle) + 'deg)'});
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.compass_container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.compass_container .square {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.compass_container .square:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.compass_container .square:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}

.compass_container .square:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: orange;
}

.arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
  border-bottom: 60px solid white;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(320deg);
-webkit-transition: transform .25s ease;
     -moz-transition: transform .25s ease;
      -ms-transition: transform .25s ease;
       -o-transition: transform .25s ease;
          transition: transform .25s ease;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="compass_container" id="compass">
  <a id="square-1" class="square" href=""></a>
  <a id="square-2" class="square" href=""></a>
  <a id="square-3" class="square" href=""></a>
  <a id="square-4" class="square" href=""></a>
  <span class="arrow"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```